# web page with multiple users or sessions

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm working on a project where I want `1-to-n` number of people to be able to access the same instance of a web page simultaneously.

An example of this would be something like iscribble.net where a person can create a drawing board, and other users can enter this board and draw simultaneously on the same board and chat etc...

what is this called? I can't find the right search term to look up a tutorial or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try "real-time collaboration," which is often achieved through WebSockets or similar technology.

[Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) is a popular JavaScript implementation of WebSockets.

Comment: "multi-user concurrency" may also work. I would use sockets, for sure.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is indeed websockets. However, push notifications, depending on complexity and interaction of your idea may be what you really need. There are different services that offer these things, as well as many open source solutions that come packaged with such capability.

Parse.com is great for a beginner for a small push enabled app with a limited number of requests. (I do not work for Parse).

A websocket app in my opinion is for an advanced developer even when the websockets are handled by a server side game solution with functionality ready to go. I'd check out push on parse.com first in a prototype to get your feet wet and see if it works.